# Spacy 2.0 Matcher: add() takes at least 4 positional arguments (3 given)

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I'm trying to make [Spacy's](http://spacy.io) [matcher example](https://spacy.io/api/matcher) from the [official documentation](https://spacy.io/api) work on my machine.

```
from spacy.matcher import Matcher

matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab) 
pattern = [{'LOWER': "hello"}, {'LOWER': "world"}] 
matcher.add("HelloWorld", None, pattern) 
doc = nlp(u'hello world!') 
matches = matcher(doc)
```

Unfortunately I encounter the following error:

**TypeError: add() takes at least 4 positional arguments (3 given)**

The corresponding source code can be found [here](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/master/spacy/matcher.pyx), the important part is

```
def add(self, key, on_match, *patterns):
    """Add a match-rule to the matcher. A match-rule consists of: an ID
        key, an on_match callback, and one or more patterns.
```

Spacy has recently been updated to version 2.0, I installed that version and also successfully linked the English model to it. Feels like I'm missing something very obvious here, but I don't see what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is indeed strange and I wasn't able to reproduce the error using your example (on spaCy v2.0.2, it worked perfectly fine for me). So the easiest explanation is that somehow, your script is actually executing the *wrong* `spacy`. (spaCy v1.x also had a `Matcher.add()` method, which took [4 positional arguments](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/v1.x/spacy/matcher.pyx#L298), so this would fit the error.)

Executing the wrong `spacy` can happen if you previously had spaCy v1.x installed and it's still on your `PYTHONPATH` (in a different environment, system Python etc.). It could also be that you installed spaCy, but forgot to tell pip to upgrade, i.e. by running `pip install -U spacy`.

The easiest way to find out is to add the following line at the top of your file:

```
print(spacy.__version__)
```

Btw, if it turns out you need to re-install or upgrade to the new version, don't forget to download the new models as well!

Comment: Turns out I forgot to tell virtualenv to use Python 3 when I set up a new environment. Hence it was using Spacy version 1 indeed. Thanks for your hint, really appreciate that the Spacy core team reacts so fast.